# How to get file creation date on browser using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-file-upload, html5-filesystem

I need to find out the file creation date and file last modified date while uploading the xls file, I have to do some calculation on this 2 dates.

By using below code I can easily get file last modified date.

```
$('#userfile').bind('change', function() {
  //this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.
  alert((this.files[0].lastModifiedDate));
  alert((this.files[0].DateCreated));
  $file_full_path =this.files[0].mozFullPath;
  alert(alert);
});
```

I am not able to find out the the file creation date. can anybody please help me.

I have also tried it via php but it is not possible via php because php doesn't send this information to server.

Please tell me is there any way to get this information.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can not get the creation date. Only the last modified date is available in file properties.

source:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-file-creation-date-before-upload

For PHP there is a thread here that provides answer: [PHP: how can I get file creation date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401320/php-how-can-i-get-file-creation-date)

Comment: I preferred my answer with its contractions and partial sentences but I guess I can't fight proper formal grammar.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlike the `lastModified` property, there is no HTML DOM `dateCreated` property. So if JS needs to access the creation date of a document, it has to access it via the metadata of the file for which it should have access to the file system.

JS not having access to the file system is a security feature in the browsers. But, in-case if someone is wanting to know how to get the creation date for the document for JS as in NodeJS (which of-course has the access to the file-system), then they can use the `file system` module to get the `birthtime` property as follows:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

var file = "location-of-my-file";
var dateCreated = fs.statSync(file).birthtime;

console.log("This File was born on:" + dateCreated);
```

NOTE : The above is only if you are programming a NodeJS app. This will not run on a normal web-browser, and will instead give the following console error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.