# How to retrieve original time of creation of a downloaded file?

Tags: php, file

Have some issues while retrieving original creation date from file.
So long file is taken from localhost and already was there so either filectime or filemtime works fine.
I need to do something with files which was downloaded from google drive. I can see in file properties that there are something like "medium created" in addition to "creation date" and "change date" but I can't get it.
Both creation date and change date are the time I've downloaded the file, and "medium created" is the only one original creation time.
Can someone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: how can I get file creation date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401320/php-how-can-i-get-file-creation-date)

Comment: Unfortunetly not. One more time - neither filectime nor filemtime work in some cases. There is a third tag I try to take. I'll update if I'll find the solution.

Comment: The original creation time can only be preserved with the download process that supports preserving that. Otherwise it is lost. For some specific media type, there might be other metadata you can look for. But that depends on the file format. What kind of file are you concerning?

Comment: @KoalaYeung, it's all about .jpg .png. I just needed to bring some order in my backup collection from the last 15 years... More cases will I ask about later. Have you some protip on how to retrieve creation time while downloading from google-tools?